# Como una recibir una peticion Ajax que devuelve un listado en Json y convertirlo en un listado de una clase (model)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

Estoy haciendo una petición con Jquery usando Ajax la cual me devuelve un Json de un listado a la vista!

Como puedo crear en la vista ( usando Razor) este listado en formato Json a un listado de un modelo(clase) en específico en el momento que recibo la data ?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Para arrancar, te recomiendo que hagas un [tour] por el sitio para que veas cómo funciona la comunidad y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Adicionalmente, para que veas cómo hacer que tu pregunta tenga buena aceptación y mayor cantidad de posibles respuestas, revisate esto [ask] y [repro]. Por favor coloca un poco del código que tengas para poder tener mayor información de contexto.

Comment: Buenas, si estas usando Ajax estas ejecutando en el navegador del cliente, y las plantillas  razor se ejecutan en Servidor. Intenta poner un ejemplo de codigo de lo que estás haciendo para poder entender que es lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno como no has dado un código de ejemplo o las clases que quieres convertir te pongo yo el ejemplo y luego lo adaptas o nos das tus modelos y editare mi respuesta!

```
public class AuthorModel
{
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;set;
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get; set;
    }
}



public class AuthorDTO
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

Una vez sabiendo el modelo de entrada y el de salida utilizaremos **AutoMapper** para convertir de un modelo a otro (esto es para que lo haga automático... también podrías mapear las cosas a mano)

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<AuthorModel, AuthorDTO>();
        });
IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
source.Id = 1;
source.FirstName = "Joydip";
source.LastName = "Kanjilal";
source.Address = "India";
var destination = iMapper.Map<AuthorModel, AuthorDTO>(source);
```

**Esto funcionara siempre que las clases se llamen igual!** 
Si tus clases tienen diferentes propriedades tendrás que configurar el **AutoMapper** para que sepa las propriedades donde van.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<AuthorModel, AuthorDTO>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.ContactDetails,
           opts => opts.MapFrom(source => source.Contact));
        });
```

Este ejemplo lo que hace es que en el Modelo tienes una propriedad con nombres diferentes entonces lo que le dices es que en el destino la propriedad **ContactDetails** pille el valor del origen de la propriedad **Contact**.